# Twitter-HBC cannot find SchemeRegistryFactory

Tags: android, apache, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to run [Twitter HBC](https://github.com/twitter/hbc) on Android with Android Studio.

I get the following error:

```
01-10 02:05:45.151  12662-12662/com.example.lgorse.twitter_test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lgorse.twitter_test, PID: 12662
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory
            at com.twitter.hbc.ClientBuilder.<init>(ClientBuilder.java:102)
            at com.example.lgorse.twitter_test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:123)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I checked online and it looks like the SchemeRegistry class is deprecated in apache - I'm guessing this is tied to versions of Apache being compiled as dependencies in my project.

I'm just not sure a) how to troubleshoot if this is the problem b) if this is the actual problem.

Here is my gradle build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lgorse.twitter_test"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.twitter:hbc-core:2.2.0'
    //compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
   // compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.5'
}
```

I commented out guava and apache dependencies - this was an experiment to see if simply adding these lines would override whatever dependencies Android Studio adds by default. Did not change anything.

Comment: Any news about this?

Comment: I'm looking into this as well. It seems like the issue is that android uses an older version of org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient that is built in. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: This is so old - but my solution was to use Twitter4J which is well-maintained and doesn't feature these headaches.